# How do I design pages for multiple user roles in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard, xcode8, uistoryboard

I am designing an app that has three different user roles for example something like  Enterprise, Small Business, Merchant but not those specifically and I went ahead and made separate storyboards and views for how each user would see their own pages and realized that I had no way to connect the three users. Overall there are certain areas of the app where each user would have identical pages, but they have similar layouts but their own particular design style. One of the users has read and write privileges on certain areas of the app where the other two would only be able to read.

I have had difficulty finding a suitable solution online, but if there is one could someone point me in the right direction, please? Otherwise is the appropriate solution to include each separate page for how each user would see it and connect them all in the `main.storyboard` file and then just hide the pages that shouldn't be seen? Would doing so clutter the storyboard space and slow things down when i go to run the simulator or when users are on their perspective sides in the app?

Comment: Any advice at all would be appreciated!